# Angular Schema Form condition

Tags: angularjs, json, schema, jsonschema, angular-schema-form

I'm using Angular Schema Form to generate a form with JSON Schema
I want to show the email textfield when the user enters the string abc, however the email textfield never appear after entering abc. I think that the problem is in the *scope of the variable name* or in *condition: "name=='abc'"*
May you give me a hand? there is the code

HTML

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/tv4/tv4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/objectpath/lib/ObjectPath.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-schema-form/dist/schema-form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-schema-form/dist/bootstrap-decorator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form sf-schema="schema" sf-form="form" sf-model="model"></form>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['schemaForm']);
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.schema = {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Comment",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "title": "Name",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "email": {
                "title": "Email",
                "type": "string"
            }
        }

    };

    $scope.form = [
        "name",
        {key: "email",
            condition: "name=='abc'"
        },
        {
            "type": "submit",
            "style": "btn-info",
            "title": "OK"
        }
    ];
    $scope.model = {};
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [docs](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/index.md#condition) you can see that you can't use name directly, as condition works with anything on scope, not just the model. So replacing "name" with "model.name=='abc'" for example will work. See my [example here](http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html#/274a6541b92feb7553c03b2033640b81).